# JSON file read 3840 error

Tags: objective-c, json

Reading this file [city.list.us.json.gz](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/city.list.us.json.gz) (uncompressed) gets an error (3840) doing:

```
    NSString * path = [mb pathForResource:@"city.list.us" ofType:@"json" inDirectory:@"JSON"];
    NSString * string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfUTF8File:path];
    NSData * data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"isValidJSONObject:%@", [NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:data] ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    NSError * bobo = nil;
    id blob = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&bobo];
    [NSApp presentError:bobo];
```

which reads ok - length 1873878 bytes, looks ok in vi (set list), but does not yield a non-nil object.

A head -4 of the file shows:

```
{"_id":4070245,"name":"Jones Crossroads","country":"US","coord":{"lon":-85.484657,"lat":31.21073}}
{"_id":4344544,"name":"Vernon Parish","country":"US","coord":{"lon":-93.183502,"lat":31.11685}}
{"_id":4215307,"name":"Pennick","country":"US","coord":{"lon":-81.55899,"lat":31.313}}
{"_id":5285039,"name":"Black Bear Spring","country":"US","coord":{"lon":-110.288139,"lat":31.386209}}
```

To my un-expert JSON eyes, it appears this is a file of cites, has an object per line with 4 values (_id,name,country,coord), last an object containing 2 values (lat,lon).

Also tried NSASCIIStringEncoding for the NSData conversion but no joy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not valid JSON. It's a large number of JSON dictionaries but they are not related to each other.

Most likely the expected JSON (an array of dictionaries) is supposed to look like

```
[{"_id":4070245,"name":"Jones Crossroads","country":"US","coord":{"lon":-85.484657,"lat":31.21073}},
{"_id":4344544,"name":"Vernon Parish","country":"US","coord":{"lon":-93.183502,"lat":31.11685}},
{"_id":4215307,"name":"Pennick","country":"US","coord":{"lon":-81.55899,"lat":31.313}},
{"_id":5285039,"name":"Black Bear Spring","country":"US","coord":{"lon":-110.288139,"lat":31.386209}}]
```

I wrapped the whole text in square brackets `[]` and added commas at the end of each line.

Comment: Huh. So I suppose the file wasn't intended to be digested as a single repository which I'd want to but hesitated to muck with it not knowing. I guess if it fails I'll walk the string by line and assemble it myself; it's ~20K lines!

Comment: You can open it in any text editor then replace `}}` with `}},` and add `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end. PS: JSON its supposed to use `NSUTF8StringEncoding`